# Spring security j_spring_security_check strange redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

I'm receiving some odd redirects from j_spring_security_check

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/index.html" />
    <logout />
</http>
```

When correct credentials are entered I get redirect to /favicon.ico. I expect redirect to /index.html instead.

(Running with gwt-maven-plugin embedded web-server, spring-security 3.2.5 + spring-bom 4.0.2)

Comment: No you will be redirected to the requested URL and as everything is protected that also includes the favicon. Setting the `default-target-url` doesn't force anything it only specifies the page to goto when there is no target-url to goto unless you set the `always-use-default-target` attribute to `true` then it always overrides the requested URL.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand this was a redirect to initial requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by adding rule:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER" />
```